# Call Aspx java script function from ascx code behind file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I have a JavaScript function in aspx page and this aspx page had several ascx control in it.

I need to call that JavaScript function from one of its ascx control code behind file. I tried below approach but it is not working as expected. Any suggestion please.

in aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Disable() 
    {
        // some code
        // return;
    }
```

in ascx code behind file:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "Script", "Disable();", True)
```

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Script", "Disable();", true);
```

RegisterClientScriptBlock writes the javascript content at the top of the HTML page content while RegisterStartupScript writes the content at the bottom.
Chances are that your inline function 'Disable()` is below the code calling it, thus it does not found when fired.